# Redireccionar a otra pagina y que te posicione en un lugar exacto de la otra pagina

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc-5

necesito ayuda

Tengo una pagina de preguntas, pero hay distintos bloques de preguntas, y en otra pagina tengo todas las respuestas de esas preguntas. 
Mi intención es que cuando seleccione un bloque de preguntas al momento de direccionar a la otra página también me ubique en el lugar exacto de las repuestas de ese bloque de preguntas.

Comment: Hola! Te doy la bienvenida a [es.so] por favor termina el [tour] para que sepas el funcionamiento del sitio y revisa [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad :)

Comment: Deberias de agregar tu codigo, de otra forma es imposible ayudarte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta identificar el área donde quieres posicionar, lo común seria que le asignaras un identificador a esa área, por ejemplo:

```
href="pagina#dirigir_aqui"
```

En la nueva pagina tendrías que tener algo asi:

```
<div id="dirigir_aqui"></div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias :) . Exactamente lo que buscaba.